# how can I use `#'` sign more gracefully? or more understandable for others?

Tags: r, rstudio

just learnt a symble `#'`. In rstudio, when use `@` after `#'`, it comes with many preset keywords, how can I use the remark sign more gracefully? Or where can I edit the keyword?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to access S4 objects? See http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S4.html

Comment: Those are roxygen2 comments.  Most of them correspond to fields in Rd help files.